# Place card container over other containers Vuetify VueJs

Tags: vuetify.js

I have this codePen : https://codepen.io/anon/pen/KBzERJ

If you scroll down you can see the card. I need this card to appear above the red container. So the red container fill the screen and the floating card in the middle of the screen above the red container.

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: () => ({
    drawer: null
  }),

  props: {
    source: String
  }
})
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet prefetch" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:300,400,500,700|Material+Icons">
<link rel="stylesheet prefetch" href="https://unpkg.com/vuetify/dist/vuetify.min.css">
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue/dist/vue.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vuetify/dist/vuetify.min.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <v-app id="inspire">
    <v-content>
      <v-container style="background:red" fill-height> </v-container>
      <v-container fluid fill-height>
        <v-layout align-center justify-center>
          <v-flex xs12 sm8 md4>
            <v-card class="elevation-12">
              <v-toolbar dark color="primary">
                <v-toolbar-title>Login form</v-toolbar-title>
                <v-spacer></v-spacer>
                <v-tooltip bottom>
                  <v-btn icon large :href="source" target="_blank" slot="activator">
                    <v-icon large>code</v-icon>
                  </v-btn>
                  <span>Source</span>
                </v-tooltip>
              </v-toolbar>
              <v-card-text>
                <v-form>
                  <v-text-field prepend-icon="person" name="login" label="Login" type="text"></v-text-field>
                  <v-text-field prepend-icon="lock" name="password" label="Password" id="password" type="password"></v-text-field>
                </v-form>
              </v-card-text>
              <v-card-actions>
                <v-spacer></v-spacer>
                <v-btn color="primary">Login</v-btn>
              </v-card-actions>
            </v-card>
          </v-flex>
        </v-layout>
      </v-container>

    </v-content>
  </v-app>
</div>
```

Answer (score 4):

See updated [codepen](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/vaGPMW?editors=1010)

Keep this structure. Basically keep `<v-container fluid fill-height>` inside `<v-container style="background:red" fill-height>`

```
<div id="app">
  <v-app id="inspire">
    <v-content>
     <v-container style="background:red" fill-height>  
      <v-container fluid fill-height>
        <v-layout align-center justify-center>
          <v-flex xs12 sm8 md4>
            <v-card class="elevation-12">
              <v-toolbar dark color="primary">
                <v-toolbar-title>Login form</v-toolbar-title>
                <v-spacer></v-spacer>
                <v-tooltip bottom>
                  <v-btn
                    icon
                    large
                    :href="source"
                    target="_blank"
                    slot="activator"
                  >
                    <v-icon large>code</v-icon>
                  </v-btn>
                  <span>Source</span>
                </v-tooltip>
              </v-toolbar>
              <v-card-text>
                <v-form>
                  <v-text-field prepend-icon="person" name="login" label="Login" type="text"></v-text-field>
                  <v-text-field prepend-icon="lock" name="password" label="Password" id="password" type="password"></v-text-field>
                </v-form>
              </v-card-text>
              <v-card-actions>
                <v-spacer></v-spacer>
                <v-btn color="primary">Login</v-btn>
              </v-card-actions>
            </v-card>
          </v-flex>
        </v-layout>
      </v-container>
     </v-container>  
    </v-content>
  </v-app>
</div>
```

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: () => ({
    drawer: null
  }),

  props: {
    source: String
  }
})
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet prefetch" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:300,400,500,700|Material+Icons">
<link rel="stylesheet prefetch" href="https://unpkg.com/vuetify/dist/vuetify.min.css">
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue/dist/vue.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vuetify/dist/vuetify.min.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <v-app id="inspire">
    <v-content>
      <v-container style="background:red" fill-height>
        <v-container fluid fill-height>
          <v-layout align-center justify-center>
            <v-flex xs12 sm8 md4>
              <v-card class="elevation-12">
                <v-toolbar dark color="primary">
                  <v-toolbar-title>Login form</v-toolbar-title>
                  <v-spacer></v-spacer>
                  <v-tooltip bottom>
                    <v-btn icon large :href="source" target="_blank" slot="activator">
                      <v-icon large>code</v-icon>
                    </v-btn>
                    <span>Source</span>
                  </v-tooltip>
                </v-toolbar>
                <v-card-text>
                  <v-form>
                    <v-text-field prepend-icon="person" name="login" label="Login" type="text"></v-text-field>
                    <v-text-field prepend-icon="lock" name="password" label="Password" id="password" type="password"></v-text-field>
                  </v-form>
                </v-card-text>
                <v-card-actions>
                  <v-spacer></v-spacer>
                  <v-btn color="primary">Login</v-btn>
                </v-card-actions>
              </v-card>
            </v-flex>
          </v-layout>
        </v-container>
      </v-container>
    </v-content>
  </v-app>
</div>
```

**Another Way**

Add a class on container containing the login form and add the following CSS

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: () => ({
    drawer: null
  }),

  props: {
    source: String
  }
})
```

```css
.v-content__wrap {
  position: relative;
}

.login-container {
  position: absolute;
  padding: 20px;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet prefetch" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:300,400,500,700|Material+Icons">
<link rel="stylesheet prefetch" href="https://unpkg.com/vuetify/dist/vuetify.min.css">
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue/dist/vue.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vuetify/dist/vuetify.min.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <v-app id="inspire">
    <v-content>
      <v-container style="background:red" fill-height> </v-container>
      <v-container fluid fill-height login-container>
        <v-layout align-center justify-center>
          <v-flex xs12 sm8 md4>
            <v-card class="elevation-12">
              <v-toolbar dark color="primary">
                <v-toolbar-title>Login form</v-toolbar-title>
                <v-spacer></v-spacer>
                <v-tooltip bottom>
                  <v-btn icon large :href="source" target="_blank" slot="activator">
                    <v-icon large>code</v-icon>
                  </v-btn>
                  <span>Source</span>
                </v-tooltip>
              </v-toolbar>
              <v-card-text>
                <v-form>
                  <v-text-field prepend-icon="person" name="login" label="Login" type="text"></v-text-field>
                  <v-text-field prepend-icon="lock" name="password" label="Password" id="password" type="password"></v-text-field>
                </v-form>
              </v-card-text>
              <v-card-actions>
                <v-spacer></v-spacer>
                <v-btn color="primary">Login</v-btn>
              </v-card-actions>
            </v-card>
          </v-flex>
        </v-layout>
      </v-container>

    </v-content>
  </v-app>
</div>
```

**Another way as suggested in comments**

Just keep one fill-height container

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: () => ({
    drawer: null
  }),

  props: {
    source: String
  }
})
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet prefetch" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:300,400,500,700|Material+Icons">
<link rel="stylesheet prefetch" href="https://unpkg.com/vuetify/dist/vuetify.min.css">
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue/dist/vue.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vuetify/dist/vuetify.min.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <v-app id="inspire">
    <v-content>
      <v-container style="background:red" fluid fill-height login-container>
        <v-layout align-center justify-center>
          <v-flex xs12 sm8 md4>
            <v-card class="elevation-12">
              <v-toolbar dark color="primary">
                <v-toolbar-title>Login form</v-toolbar-title>
                <v-spacer></v-spacer>
                <v-tooltip bottom>
                  <v-btn icon large :href="source" target="_blank" slot="activator">
                    <v-icon large>code</v-icon>
                  </v-btn>
                  <span>Source</span>
                </v-tooltip>
              </v-toolbar>
              <v-card-text>
                <v-form>
                  <v-text-field prepend-icon="person" name="login" label="Login" type="text"></v-text-field>
                  <v-text-field prepend-icon="lock" name="password" label="Password" id="password" type="password"></v-text-field>
                </v-form>
              </v-card-text>
              <v-card-actions>
                <v-spacer></v-spacer>
                <v-btn color="primary">Login</v-btn>
              </v-card-actions>
            </v-card>
          </v-flex>
        </v-layout>
      </v-container>

    </v-content>
  </v-app>
</div>
```

Comment: ah place the container within a container. Do you know of a way to group elements and not have any effect on the UI? For example, say I have 50 components, for arguments sake, I want to group all these and have one v-if statement, rather than have 50 v-ifs. Basically the components only show if something is true. I can accept the answer in 3 minutes

Comment: Sorry I do not know Vue works ! I just tried something logically and figured out the solution.

Comment: after testing this, I don't have the ability to place the container within the container. They must be side by side. Any ideas ?

Comment: What is the reason for 2 containers? Can't you just use the outer one? second one makes no sense?

Comment: @Traxo perhaps I havent understood the proper way of putting an app together. Basically, I have a container for the cards, and a container for the main view. I want the cards to appear over the main view; container over container. Perhaps I have misunderstood what a container is for

Comment: > `Sorry I do not know Vue works ! I just tried something logically and figured out the solution.` you mean `Vuetify`? Then how can you give proper solution to a problem? Sure you can use arbitrary html and css but that kills the purpose of the framework then.

Comment: @Traxo I never said its a proper solution, thanks for pointing that out. :) If you have a better solution, do tell, would love to learn something new :)

Comment: Both you and @thatOneGuy see if [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51378834/1981247) achieves what you wanted (perhaps I misunderstood something), but there is no need for custom styles. Just use what framework offers. I presume you follow [tag:css] tag and thus you came to answer the question here?

Answer (score 0):

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/pZymrW

Use a single container and style only that one:

```
<v-container fill-height class="red">
    <v-layout align-center justify-center>
        <v-flex xs12 sm8 md4>
             //Centered content i.e. card
        </v-flex>
    </v-layout>
</v-container>
```

Also notice that you can use `class="red"` instead of `style="background:red"` so you get `Vuetify`s colors, which is likely what you want in the first place.

Also see `v-container` [API](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/components/api-explorer) (type `v-container` in the searchbox).

Comment: My problem is, I have custom components. One is a card, and one is svg which should fill all space below the toolbar. When I show the card, i need it above the SVG. I have managed to solve this : https://codepen.io/anon/pen/ejZaQL not sure if this is the optimal way

Comment: @thatOneGuy Ah well, you didn't mention it in the question, lol. Still you could use `background-image: ` on the container perhaps so that hierarchy is preserved, tho I'm not sure which approach is better for svg background.